# has_many and has_many through with a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a users table where the users can be 'friends' with each other. The following relationship is in `user.rb` and works correctly:

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

When I run `User.first.friendships` or `User.first.friends`, everything works fine.

Here is my problem... I added a column on the `friendships` table called `accepted_on`. I only want friendships where `accepted_on` isn't nil. I used the following code to do that:

```
has_many :friendships, -> (object) { where.not(accepted_on: nil) }
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

Now if I run `User.first.friendships`, everything works according to plan. If I run `User.first.friends` I get the following error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `object` in your association. So why not remove it?

change

```
has_many :friendships, -> (object) { where.not(accepted_on: nil) }
```

to

```
has_many :friendships,-> { where.not(accepted_on: nil) }
```